# routing in rails - displaying the contents of one controller in a different view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, routes

I am trying to figure out how to routes the contents of one controller into that of another. 
Currently, I have two controllers -
 
1. Static Pages controller - this is very simple, all it used for is to yield one page (with tabbable pages)

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
  end
end
```

2.Guides controller - This is where a user may (currently) add guides to the db.

```
class GuidesController < ApplicationController
  def home
  end

  def show
   @guide = Guide.find(params[:id])
  end

  def index
    @guide = Guide.all
  end

  def new
   @guide = Guide.new
  end

 def create
   @guide = Guide.new(guide_params)
   if @guide.save
     redirect_to '/guides'
   else
    render 'new'
  end
end

private

def guide_params
  params.require(:guide).permit(:title, :description, :image, :date, :date_end, :extra_info)
end
```

end

I want to display the INDEX part of the controller (which currently works at '/guides', in my root directory, or 'home' in the static pages controller.

I've tried fiddling with all of this, and my last port of call is the routes.rb file. However I am not all together sure, this seems straight forward enough and its cheesing me off not being able to do it.

Comment: You want to display `index view` of your `guides` in your `home view` of your `pages`?

Comment: in routes.rb, `root to: 'guides#index'`

Comment: But htis breaks the rest of my guides controller?! I try /guides/new and i get,

undefined method `any?' for #<Guide:0x00000105719250>
Extracted source (around line #2):
1
2
3
4
5
          
  
  <% if @guide.any? %>
    <%= render 'guide_post' %>
  <% else %>
   <h1>PLEASE COME BACK SOON </h1>

Trace of template inclusion: app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb, app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the possible solutions is that you use:

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
     @guide = Guide.all
  end
end
```

and copy the code from index,html.erb of your guide to home.html.erb of static pages. 
other than that you can use rendering: [link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html)

EDIT:

use partial to show index of guides:

```
class GuidesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @guide = Guide.all
    render partial: "index"
  end
end
```

in your views of guide rename "index.html.erb" to "_index.html.erb" and
in static_pages/home.html.erb add:

```
<%= render :partial => "guides/index" %>
```

Comment: I tried this  but as i am using tabs the data then displays on every page

Comment: could you please explain what did you mean by " to yield one page (with tabbable pages)"

Comment: 'Home' is in effect just one page, that has many partials which are activated on click.

Comment: check edit of answer. I think last line is what you were looking for.

Comment: actually, now my other views wont work....
@guides.new 

undefined method `each' for #<Guide:0x000001044dfc10>

Trace of template inclusion: app/views/static_pages/_guide.html.erb, app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb, app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

Comment: why are you using "each" for making new guide? can you please add code of your guides/new.html.erb? (if thats where you got error)

Comment: <h1>Guides#new</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/guides/new.html.erb</p>
 <%= form_for(@guide) do |f| %>
 etc etc

<% end %>

I am not using 'each'. for sme reason when I visit '/guides/new' it throws the above error related to the index view...
thanks for you help by the way.

Comment: I hope your home of your StaticPages looks like this: `def home
     @guide = Guide.all 
  end`

Comment: just fiddled around, i was being dumb.
Balls of Steel, big thanks man - it worked. Fred